# Vector of structs with dynamically allocated members

Tags: c++, vector, struct

If I wanted to fill a vector with a struct, and in the struct I need to dynamically allocate/relocate the `WCHAR` arrays, how would I populate this?
I can't use `std::wstring` because I'm going to be using the members with the Windows API.
And functions like `RegQueryValueEx` require a `LPBYTE` to receive the data.

Or is there some other STL container I should be using?

Example Code:

```
typedef struct {
    WCHAR *str1;
    WCHAR *str2;
    DWORD SomeOtherStuff;
} MYSTRUCT;

vector<MYSTRUCT> myvector;
```

Comment: I have multiple reasons to believe that your design is terrible. Why not ask about the underlying problem, rather than about this highly questionable first step you decided to take?

Comment: What Kerrek may be bluntly referring to is that `RegQueryValueEx` does not allocate buffers for you so with your current struct you would need exception unsafe heap allocation among other things. The bigger question is what specific problem requires such variable amounts of data from the registry?

Comment: Well I'm going to be enumerating keys in the registry, and I want to save a few values to display to the user in a List-View control (Windows API).

Comment: @Josh: If you have a "few values" then perhaps just query them directly. Else if you are making a registry viewer of some sort check out `RegEnumKeyEx` and `RegQueryInfoKey` with some binding struct or variant to handle all types of registry data you may want to display.

Comment: @AJG85 It's not exactly a registry viewer. But there are around 20-30 keys I'm enumerating, and each one has around 5 values I want to store in some data structure for easy access. And I'm currently using `RegQueryValueEx` and `RegEnumKeyEx` to read the keys. So I was just looking for a way to implement the data structure to store the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `std::vector<WCHAR>` for the structure members. This will give your structure the necessary copy/move semantics to put it in a `vector` and, when you need a raw pointer for some API, it's avaiable as `&str1[0]`.

Remember to make sure it's large enough (either by initialising it to the required size, or calling `resize()`) before doing anything that will access the data. Also remember that pointers and iterators to the data will become invalid when the vector is resized.

Comment: Should note you have to use `resize` or `reserve`, unless I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @Josh: Yes, you must always make sure it's large enough for whatever you need to do with it.

Comment: Should I be using `resize` or `reserve`?

Comment: In this case, `resize` because you're going to be writing data directly into the vector's memory. Use `reserve` if you're going to be calling `push_back` or `insert` on the vector, and don't want to change its size yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor for your struct.  And then all the copies made of each instance would have their own copy of the dynamically allocated memory.

Or you could just use `std::wstring`

`std::wstring` provides an accessor method `c_str`, which gives you a pointer to the underlying null-terminated string.  This lets you use std::wstring with C APIs.

```
std::wstring wide_string;
some_win_api_call( wide_string.c_str() );  // sending a string to winapi
```

To get a string from the winapi, you need to allocate a buffer yourself, and pass in a pointer to the buffer, along with the length of the buffer.

```
wide_string.reserve( 256 );  // allocate some space to receive a string
get_string_from_winapi( &wide_string[0], wide_string.capacity() );
```

You might need to do `wide_string.capacity() * sizeof(wchar_t)` if the api wants the length in bytes.  My example assumes length in characters.

Comment: There's no way to get a non-const pointer to the data in a `wstring`, which I think the OP needs. You'd need a `vector<WCHAR>` for that.

Comment: And note that hacking it with `reserve()` and `&string[0]` like that gives undefined behaviour, even if it is likely to appear to work on many compilers. At the very least, use `resize()` rather than `reserve()` so that future string operations have a chance of working.